# Accessing assets stored in AAR from application

Tags: android, aar, android-assets

I have a library project which includes some `TFLite` models. I want to be able to distribute the library and include the models in the AAR's `assets` folder. I've put everything in the `assets` folder and when inspecting the resulting AAR, I see that the models exists.

My question is, how can I access these models? either from the library itself (preferably) or from the application that uses it?

If I look try and access the assets the normal way for an application

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
am.list(assetFolder)
```

I get an empty list.

I saw many posts about including assets in an android AAR library but none that referred to how to actually use these assets, so am I missing something very basic here?

**EDIT**
This is how the AAR is structured
[image]

Inside the `assets` folder I have a `resources` folder which contains the models
so

```
- AAR
-- assets
--- resources
---- model
```

I tried different values for `assetFolder` in the code, `/`, `resources`, all gave empty lists

Comment: Could you share how your assets folder in the aar looks like? And also what's the value of the `assetFolder` variable

Comment: hm, that's weird. Have you tried to just pass an empty string as a parameter of `.list`? When I did so, I was able to see the entire contents of the assets folder, also including those that are coming transitively from a library.

Comment: Well, this was weird indeed. After you wrote this I tried again and this time it worked. Weird. I've checked this several times. Probably had something else interfering

Comment: lol. Maybe your app/lib wasn't fully recompiled after adding new assets or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
am.list("resources/model")
```

Just tested with aar and it works. Be careful, `list` returns directories and files in the specified path, it doesn't show files in subfolders